# How to detect image load failure and if fail, attempt reload until success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have some images loading from offsite and have no control over their availability.  I've found that under heavy load they are sometimes failing to load, but on a quick refresh they'll show right up.

Is there a way to detect if images fail to load and then if so, evoke a reload on the img src until it loads?  If so, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here something I compiled which might help. I couldn't manage to do testing of this please let me know if you are having any issues.

```
$(function() {
   var $images = $('img.imageClassUpdateAtInterval:not([src="/assets/spinner.gif"])');

  // Now, no such image with
   // a spinner
   if($images.length === 0 && window.imageLocator)
     clearInterval(window.imageLocator);


    window.imageLocator = setInterval(function() {
        $images.each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.data('src')) {
                $this.data('src', $this.prop('src'));
            }

            $this.prop('src', $this.data('src') + '?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime());
            console.log($this.prop('src'));
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);

   // suppose, an error occured during
   // locating the src (source) of the
   // image - image not found, network
   // unable to locate the resource etc.
   // it will fall in each time on error
   // occurred 
   $('img.imageClassUpdateAtInterval').error(
          function () {   
                 // set a broken image
                 $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/assets/broken.gif"); 
                 // setting this up in relative
                 // position
                 $(this).css("position", "relative");
                 $(this).apppend("<span>Error occured</span>");
                 $(this).find("span").css({"position": "absolute", "background-color": "#252525", "padding": ".3em", "bottom": "0"});
   });

});
```

The above solution is compiled from two different solutions commenced by [@user113716](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922962/134743) and [@travis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168448/134743)

Comment: That is excellent input. Thanks!  I like the additional information.  Here's the original js I'm using to actually reload some images based on a class every 60 seconds.  I would *very* much appreciate seeing this integrated into the following code I'm using so that these two examples you have are properly integrated (I'm quite new to working in js at any significant level): http://j.mp/wzi7FI

Comment: Sorry ylluminate. I got away. I have edited my post and I hope this will help you.

Comment: Worked out real well, thanks!  Have a few tweaks to make, but you got it down well enough.  Super job.

Answer (score 18):

```
<img onerror="dosomthing()" ...>
```

Comment: That's `$('#myImg').bind('error', function(e){ ... });` in jQuery :)

Comment: The most straightforward solution for replacing images that fail to load with a default image.

Comment: What should "dosomthing()" do to reload the image?

Comment: @Barmar : It might be changing the `src` of the `img` to a default resource : Something like : `$('#img1').attr('src','images/no-profile-photo.png')` . Or as you suggested , a logical code to re attempt to load the same image .

Answer (score 5):

take a look at this code:

```
$('img.autoFix').error(function(){
    var src = this.src;
    this.src = src.substr(0, src.indexOf('?')) + '?t=' + new Date().getTime()
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it get into an infinite loop in case the image does not exist or there's some other persistent issue with it?

Comment: it will, but if you want you can use data attribute to limit number of tries.

Comment: ... or use a setTimeout in the error function to not make it reload like crazy.

Answer (score 4):

After mixing together a few ideas from other answers, along with my own, I came up with something that worked for me:

Add this to your img elements:

```
onerror="tryAgain(this)"
```

Script:

```
<script>  
  function tryAgain(e) 
  {
    setTimeout(reloadImg, 1000, e);
  }

  function reloadImg(e)
  {
    var source = e.src;
    e.src = source;
  }
</script>
```

You can of course change the timeout to whatever you want. (forgive me for not using $ in my answer; I'm new to JS and haven't used JQuery at all).

Comment: jQuery isn't needed anymore

Answer (score 2):

This a very simple approach that handles all images on the page.

---

https://github.com/doomhz/jQuery-Image-Reloader

**jQuery Image Reloader**

Forces the browser to retry loading the broken images. A decent solution for images stored in a cloud (i.e Amazon S3).

**Why and when to use it?**

This plugin is effective when you load images from a cloud (i.e. Amazon S3) and the CDN has a delay until the image is accessible. The browser will display a broken image icon instead and won't retry to reload it. jQuery Image Reloader will take care of that.

**Plugin code**

The only code you need to activate the plugin is this:

```
$(".slow-images").imageReloader();
```