# How do I lazy load images I haven't downloaded yet in JavaFX WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx, javafx-11

I'm making an email client that uses JavaFX WebView to display email HTML files. To make it responsive and quick, I want to have inline images appear in the email as they are downloaded locally. I looked up options for doing this and I came across the concept of lazy loading. So far I have found and tried to implement this [script](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/5-brilliant-ways-to-lazy-load-images-for-faster-page-loads):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var allimages= document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i=0; i<allimages.length; i++) {
        if (allimages[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            allimages[i].setAttribute('src', allimages[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}, false)
</script>
```

I'd go through the file, changing *src*s to a fake name, adding/replacing *data-src* from each *img* element to be the proper path/name, and finally append the script to the end of the *body* element.
I'm pretty new to HTML past the basics, and JS isn't one for showing error logs, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My guess is that the script ***is*** working properly to a degree but works best when images are being streamed from an online src. My situation would have the files not even exist in a location until sometime after the HTML is loaded into the view.
If this isn't achievable, I know I could just code the WebView through Java to reload each time an image finishes downloading. I was just hoping to find something a little more elegant/potentially less jarring to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a solution and have posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499609/11268550).**

It turns out that lazy loading isn't what I was looking for. Lazy loading just loads images later so the page can appear. My problem was handling load failure, which lazy loading doesn't account for. I'll flag this as a duplicate, but I'll leave the title of this question unedited so other people have a better chance of finding it.